# Multiple Interface inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I have two interfaces with same method

```
   interface FirstInterface
   {
     int add(int x, int y);
   }

   interface SecondInterface
   {
      int add(int x, int y);
   }

   class TestInterface:FirstInterface,SecondInterface
   {
     public TestInterface() {}

     public int add(int x, int y)
     {
        return x + y;
     }
   }
```

and in my main class

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestInterface t = new TestInterface();
        int result = t.add(3, 4);

    }
```

The compiler doesnt give any error and the result is displayed..

Is it right ??  shouldn't we use `FirstInterface.add` ??

does it mean **interfaces are resolved at compile time** ??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's the subject of [Explicit or Implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173157.aspx) implementation of interfaces.

If you implement `Interface A` and `Interface B`, and they both have a member called `Foo`, which is a method, then if you implement these interfaces in one class, your only method `Foo` would count for both of them. This is by design, and frankly, I think there is no other way around for this.

To implement them separately, you have to use `Explicit Interface Implementation`, that is, you prefix the name of the `Foo` method with the name of the interface and a dot, like `InterfaceA.Foo` and `InterfaceB.Foo`.

Quoting from [C# specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf):

> 20.3 Fully qualified interface member names
>
> An interface member is sometimes referred to by a qualified interface member name. A qualified interface member name consists of a name identifying the interface in which the member is declared, followed by a dot, followed by the name of the member.

Comment: Thank you saeed..That was very simple and precise

Answer (score 0):

This is implicit interface implementation, so the method is now associated with the instance of TestResult as well. This means you can call the method on both instances with the concrete class handle as well as instances with an IFirstInterface handle.

```
FirstInterface interfaceHandle = new TestInterface();
interfaceHandle.add();
```

Will also work

Answer (score 0):

[Blog about Implementation.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mhop/archive/2006/12/12/implicit-and-explicit-interface-implementations.aspx)

What you are doing here is implementing the interface implicitly.with implicit interface implementation you access the interface methods and properties as if they were part of the class itself.

Whereas in explicit implementation you can access them by treating them as interface